# Collecting classes definitions on the fly while parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, compilation, bison

Currently, I'm working on a simple compiler project.

Suppose having the following grammar:

```
file_input : file_item*
;

file_item : class_def
          | variable_decl
;

class_def : 'class' NAME scope
;

variable_decl : 'dim' NAME 'as' NAME
;
```

now, while building our `symbol table` if we declared a variable before the class definition we will get semantic error, because it won't find the class required in the `symbol table`

simply, we need let the compiler wait till the class name is defined, so declaring a variable of type `foo` and defining the class `foo` later won't disturb the compiler.

any suggestion on how to achieve that ?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll require a multi-pass approach:

First walk over the AST once to build the table mapping class names to the class definition without doing anything else that would require performing lookups on the table. Then walk it a second time, with the table already built and you'll be able to loop up any class you want when encountering a variable definition.

Comment: actually, I thought about that, but this way will require, reading the file again reading the same tokens from the Lexer, I hope there's a new approach for doing that using 1 pass, thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Maher: The point of building an AST is to not have to read the file again. The AST needs to contain all the information you need for subsequent passes, organized into a more useful structure (a tree or a DAG).

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be that when class `foo` is used in a variable declaration and it doesn't yet exist, create the class `foo` immediately, but add a flag (something like "undefined") to the class definition. When the class is actually defined later on, update the class definition in the symbol table and remove the "undefined" flag.

At the end of the compile, look through in the symbol table for any classes that are still flagged as "undefined" and report the error then. It might be useful to record the line number of the first use of the class for error reporting purposes.

This will work for now, but later on when you want to check for correct member access within a class, it will be tricky to do without the full class definition. You could do a similar thing where you defer the parsing of the member access until you have the definition, but overall I think it would be harder than just multi-pass as sepp2k suggested.